# Error: maven-site-plugin:3.7.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: java, maven

This is my first maven program. I have succeeded to run "mvn compile", "mvn test", "mvn clean" but this error appears when I "mvn site."

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.7.1:site (default-site) on project Hello: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.7.1:site failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.7.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.7.1 -> org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-markdown:jar:1.8 -> com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-all:jar:0.18.4 -> com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-html-parser:jar:0.18.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-html-parser:jar:0.18.4: Could not transfer artifact com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-html-parser:pom:0.18.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.52.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]

I'm using **jdk-12.0.2** and **apache-maven-3.6.0** The following is my pom.xml and setting.xml.

**pom.xml:**

> ```
> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
>          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
>          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
>                              http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>   <groupId>com._520it.maven</groupId>
>   <artifactId>Hello</artifactId>
>   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
>   <name>Hello</name>
>   <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>           <groupId>junit</groupId>
>           <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
>           <version>4.9</version>
>           <scope>test</scope>
>       </dependency>           
>   </dependencies>
>   
>   <build>
>       <plugins>
>         <plugin>
>               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>               <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
>               <version>3.7.1</version>
>           </plugin>
>           <plugin>
>               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>               <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
>               <version>3.0.0</version>
>           </plugin>
>       </plugins>
>   </build>
> </project>
> ```

For setting.xml, I didn't change anything but indicating my jdk version.

Comment: The first issue is: `Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.52.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]` this looks like a network error... second why are you using an old Maven version 3.6.X? Get the most recent versions...also the plugins you have defined are old ...check here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ and furthermore why using an old JDK version? We have JDK 17 (LTS) in the meantime... https://dev.java/download/releases/

Comment: Thank you, that's it! The network issue. And I will update my whole set-up ASAP. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thank you to @khmarbaise! The issue is due to a "Connection timed out." I quit my proxy and tried it again, it worked!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).